# Is there a way to animate 3d Objects with c/c++ only in unreal engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I am searching for a way to animate meshes with c++ only without using blueprints, but could not find any approach.

Is UE even allowing this?

I want to add a character in a c++ project without any Blueprint and animate it with c++ only.

I tried to work with UAnimInstance but as far as i can see, this is just to extend the Unreal Engine Class for a more individual animation, but thats not the goal. The goal is to animate with c++ only.

I have tried UAnimInstance, but this does not allow to create an animation with pure c++ code.

Comment: Try UPoseableMeshComponent

Comment: I will try this, thanks for the idea. Looking forward for more ideas.

Comment: Give a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76153051/i-am-trying-to-rotate-a-bone-of-a-mesh-in-c-using-unreal-engine-5/76164281?noredirect=1#comment134396302_76164281